# Docker command RUN not working with git init --bare?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that creates an image for a GIT server.

In this Dockerfile there are three lines important for me:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/repository
WORKDIR /root/repository
RUN git init --bare
```

First two lines are working correctly, but the last line seems not to work properly. It gives no error output whatsoever, but it doesnt create all the files/directories inside `repository` folder. The folder is empty, but it should contain those files/folders:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  23 Feb 27 14:18 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   6 Feb 27 14:18 branches/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  66 Feb 27 14:18 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  73 Feb 27 14:18 description
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 242 Feb 27 14:18 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  21 Feb 27 14:18 info/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  30 Feb 27 14:18 objects/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  31 Feb 27 14:18 refs/
```

When I access the docker container via docker exec, and execute `git init --bare` by hand - everything seems to be fine...

Executing `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID git init --bare` works perfectly...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you solve your problem? I have the same and @Rumen Kyusakov hint wasn't correct in my case

Answer (score 1):

It must be something with the environment setup in the Dockerfile or the base image you use. The following minimal example works:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add git

RUN mkdir -p /root/repository
WORKDIR /root/repository
RUN git init --bare
```

You can for example verify that $GIT_DIR is not set in the base image or as build argument to `docker build`. If it is set the `git init --bare` will init the repo in $GIT_DIR instead of `/root/repository`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Found out that the Dockerfile I was inheriting from declared the directory as volume, that does not seem to work. ;)

original Dockerfile

```
...
VOLUME /var/something
...
```

my original Dockerfile

```
...
ADD pipeline_repo /var/something/v
RUN git init /var/something/my_stuff && \
    git -C /var/something/my_stuff add --all && \
    git -C /var/something/my_stuff commit --message "only commit ever"
...
```

Just changed `/var/something` to `/opt/something/my_stuff`